# Create multiple plugin in a single placeholder in django cms when using default plugins

Tags: python, django-cms

How can I create multiple plugin in a single placeholder in django cms if I am using default plugins which django cms provide?

Comment: What version of CMS? You just keep adding plugins the same way you add the first one.

Comment: It is 3.1. I have to use a text and image plugin both in same placeholder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you may have seen from the [docs](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.3.x/reference/configuration.html#cms-placeholder-conf), you can configure the plugins for a placeholder, but if you don't, then you can add any plugin you want without restriction.

So for example, you could configure a placeholder called `content` like this;

```
CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF = {
    'content': {
        'plugins': [
            'GoogleMapPlugin', 'LinkPlugin', 'TextPlugin',
        ],
        'text_only_plugins': [
            'FilePlugin', 'LinkPlugin',
        ],
        'name': gettext("Content"),
    },
```

That would allow you to add to the `content` placeholder, a `GoogleMapPlugin`, `LinkPlugin` or `TextPlugin`, but also add a `FilePlugin` or `LinkPlugin` within a `TextPlugin`.